# Sklearn.linear_model : ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 20]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to implement linear regression but when i run the code I get this error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 20] in line-->linear.fit(x_train1,y_train1) [data type of x_train1,x is series & y_ is series]`.

I changed `x=dataset.iloc[:,:-1]` datatype of x_train, `x` changes to dataframe(`y_` is still series) and it works correctly

So why it only works when `x` is dataframe eventhough `y` is still series??

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot

dataset=pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')

x=dataset.iloc[:,0]

y=dataset.iloc[:,1]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train1,x_test1,y_train1,y_test1=
train_test_split(x,y,test_size=1/3,random_state=0)

#implementing simple linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

linear=LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train1,y_train1)

y_pred=linear.predict(x_test1)
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your dataset?

Comment: YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
2.0,43525.00
2.2,39891.00
2.9,56642.00
3.0,60150.00
3.2,54445.00
3.2,64445.00
3.7,57189.00
3.9,63218.00
4.0,55794.00
4.0,56957.00
4.1,57081.00
4.5,61111.00
4.9,67938.00
5.1,66029.00
5.3,83088.00
5.9,81363.00
6.0,93940.00
6.8,91738.00
7.1,98273.00
7.9,101302.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scikit-Learn` does not accept rank 1 `array` (1 dimensional data), i.e: if you call shape method on your x:

```
x.shape
```

it will return something that looks like this `(23,)`, 23 being the number of rows where it should be `(23,1)`.

In order for it to work, try using `reshape`:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:,0]
x = x.reshape((len(x),1))
...
```

Comment: But  the data form of y_train1 is still series and sklearn is accepting it! So can u exlain why it need only first argument as dataframe?

Comment: Y is the attribute you want to predict where X is the set of features you want to use to predict Y. By default, Y is always 1 dimensional since you can't predict more than one attribute using single predict statement.

Comment: Thx bro really appreciate ur help